Which cron should I use for Symfony 6.4? I've already tried everything and the versions don't work
Which cron should I use for Symphony 6.4?
I've already tried everything and the versions don't work
composer.json
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.12",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^3.1",
        "mybuilder/cronos": "^4.0",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.28",
        "shapecode/cron-bundle": "^7.0",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/asset-mapper": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2.4",
        "symfony/form": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/stimulus-bundle": "^2.16",
        "symfony/string": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/ux-turbo": "^2.16",
        "symfony/validator": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "ext-curl": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "importmap:install": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.4.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.57",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^7.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.4.*"
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Consider reading through this https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/scheduler.html.
This should be the way to handle periodic tasks for Symfony 6.3 and above.
